# htmllabel for objective c swaps words for Right to Left Languages [Arabic]

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, label, right-to-left

I am using [HTMLLabel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/HTMLLabel) class to display html content [string with some attributes for subparts (e.g. bold ,italic and color)].I have faced some problems like `\n` should be replaced `<br/>` when appending to the content of the HTMLLabel -__- but over all every thing worked just fine until I tried to write RTL language in the html file.. The result was not expected as words are shown swapped. for example :

{السلام عليكم والرحمة }
is shown like this :
{الرحمة و عليكم السلام }

I have posted the issue in the [HTMLLabel page in GitHup](https://github.com/nicklockwood/HTMLLabel/issues/9)..

Any help is extremely appreciated..

**EDIT:**

The result I am getting from the server is a list of strings like :

"`السلام عليكم <b>والرحمة</b>`"
NOT an HTML File!

Answer (score 0):

You need these to create a HTML5 page with language as Arabic, direction as RTL, and utf-8 encoded

`<!DOCTYPE html>` For declaring it as a HTML5 page

`<html dir="rtl" lang="ar">` For direction and language

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />` For utf-8

Comment: Thank you for your prompt to help. Please see the edit to my question